# How to set image vertical when image is captured by camera?

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, imageview

I just implemented a camera in my app. However, when I take a picture and said picture is set to the image view, the image rotates. Why is this happening? When I take the picture vertically, the image view shows it horizontally and when I take the picture horizontally the image view shows it vertically. 
Here is the camera code:

```
 private fun openCamera() {
    val values = ContentValues()
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,"New Picture")
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,"From the Camera")
    image_uri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values)
    //camera intent
    val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri)
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE)


}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    //called when user presses alow or deny from premissio request
    when(requestCode){
        PERMISSION_CODE ->{
            if(grantResults.size > 0 && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                //PERMISSION FROM POPUP WAS GRANTED
                openCamera()

            }else{
                //permisson from popup was denied
                Toast.makeText(this,"Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}


@SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

    //called when image was captured from camera intet
    if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){
        //set image captured to image view
        image_view.setImageURI(image_uri)


        //get location

        //stop compass

    }
}
```

Here is my layout of the image view:

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="283dp"
    android:layout_height="331dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/image1"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.515" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem couple of months ago, and i can give you a method which i used and it worked that way. There are some differences before Android Pie and after. Anyway, with this method you will get the bitmap from the photoUri and you can use bitmap to populate imageView in the end. If you have any doubts, contact me here.

```
// Getting captured image as a bitmap
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
private fun getCapturedImage(selectedPhotoUri: Uri): Bitmap {

    val bitmap = when {
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.P -> MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
            context?.contentResolver,
            selectedPhotoUri
        )
        else -> {
            val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(context!!.contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri)
            ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
        }
    }

    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height, Matrix().apply {}, true)
    } else {
        MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context?.contentResolver, context?.let { getImageUri(it, bitmap) })
    }
}


// Getting image Uri from the bitmap, its needed for android level 6 (sdk 23)
private fun getImageUri(inContext: Context, inImage: Bitmap): Uri {
    val outImage: Bitmap = if (inImage.width > inImage.height) {
        Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(inImage, 2560, 1440, true)
    } else {
        Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(inImage, 1440, 2560, true)
    }
    val path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.contentResolver, outImage, "Title", null)
    return Uri.parse(path)

}
```

Comment: I'm having some issues with the variable context. Do you hvabe an idea why this is happening?

Comment: its just context within the fragment, if you are calling this within activity, replace context with keyword this. If that didn't help then i will give you mail or something so that you can send image of an error. @TeresaAlves

Comment: It worked, but now I have an error with the getImage

Comment: Ah yeah that's one more method, i have edited answer, check it out now. @TeresaAlves

Comment: The I should so getCapturedImge(image_uri) right? But how do I set it to the image view?

Comment: well its simple, imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap) and this bitmap parameter is the method above @TeresaAlves

Comment: The image doesn't appear on the image view. At the end of the method i put image_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap) like you said

Comment: Well i don't know then, you need to debug it and see what causing the problem, all i can do from my chair is to send you my whole class to the email or something and then you could try using it. One more thing is that this hard coded dimensions 2560, 1440 might affecting your code somehow, so you can try instead of this values, to use inImage.width and inImage.height. @TeresaAlves

Comment: I just saw that method getImageUri is only called if your device is Android less than Nougat (android 6, 5 and less) so it might not affecting you. @TeresaAlves

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening for all devices, or for some only? As far as I think this should not be happening in all devices. Have you tested for that?

You could try the solution below.. 
This happens because most phone cameras are landscape, meaning if you take the photo in portrait, the resulting photos will be rotated 90 degrees. In this case, the camera software should populate the **Exif** data with the orientation that the photo should be viewed in.

This solution should work, but is not 100 percent reliable because it depends on the phone manufacturer devive/camera Exif data.

```
    ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(photoPath);
    int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                                     ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;
    switch(orientation) {

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
        rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
        break;

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
        rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
        break;

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
        rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 270);
        break;

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
    default:
        rotatedBitmap = bitmap;
}
```

```
    public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
         Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
         matrix.postRotate(angle);
         return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(),
                               matrix, true);
    }
```

Note : If this solution does not know for you, I could provide another maybe.

Comment: Hello, I haven't tested in other devices. I've only tested on a samsung A5 2016, but I'll try the solution you just provided, thank you

Comment: Where do you declare the variable bitmap?